# Как сгенерировать .js-файл как каким-либо кодом в Node.js?

Tags: node.js

Есть какой-то JS-код, например:

```js
class TestClass {
   testMethod() {
      console.log('OK');
   }
}
```

Мы хотим, возможно немного модфицировав этот код, сохранить его в файл `output.js`:

```js
export default class TestClass {
   testMethod() {
      console.log('OK');
   }
}
```

Записать какое-либо текстовое содержимое с помощью fs.writeFile сможет любой новичок в Node.JS, в данном же вопросе речь идёт не просто о записи статического содержимого в файл, а о генерации JavaScript-файлов. Полагаю, прежде чем дело дойдёт до fs, нужно как-то предобработать JavaScript-код, который мы будем записывать в файл. Будет ли достаточно преобразовать этот код в строку, и если да, то как это сделать?
Какие средства в Node.js для этого существуют?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v11.x/docs/api/fs.html

Comment: @Suvitruf, прошу меня простить, но ссылка на документацию не является чётким ответом на вопрос. Записать какое-либо текстовое содержимое с помощью `fs.writeFile` сможет любой новичок в Node.JS, в данном же вопросе речь идёт о том, как записать в файл часть JavaScript-кода. Полагаю, прежде чем дело дойдёт до `fs`, нужно как-то предобработать JavaScript-код, который мы будем записывать в файл. Будет ли достаточно преобразовать этот код в строку, и если да, то как это сделать?